# Input today's date get tomorrow output

Tags: c, date

When I enter the date `08/01/2015` the program prints `00/00/00` instead of `08/01/2015`. What seems to be the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int month = 0;
    int day = 0;
    int year = 0;
    printf("Enter today's date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
    scanf("%i/%i/%i", &month, &day, &year);
    printf("%.2i/%.2i/%.2i", month, day, year);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check what happens if you enter 18/35/-100 . Hint: you need more sane checks.

Comment: You shouldn't really be altering the `daysPerMonth[]` array - especially as you don't reset to `28` when it is not a leap year. Better to fetch the number of days and then adjust for February in a leap year.

Comment: @WeatherVane, what do you mean?

Comment: If you extend your program so that you can "tomorrow" several dates, it will fall over. If you are going to set February's array element to `29` in a leap year, you must set it to `28` when not. But it's bad practice to tinker with your base definitions anyway. Better to make the exception at the time you need to know, for example like: `monthdays=daysPerMonth[month-1]; if (leap && month==2) monthdays++;`

Comment: @Bohemian that is SO annoying when I have just spent a half hour preparing an answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane edit the question to make to actual problem clearer, msg me, and I'll reopen it

Comment: @Bohemian the problem is that when the dates from Aug 1 to Sep 30 are entered there is an error in the output, how is that not clear?

Comment: I get the same issue with a more basic code, I broke it down to hopefully figure it out.

Comment: @xaiga29 `%i` interprets the input as `octal` number format when there is a leading `0`. The months `08` and `09` make no sense in `octal`. Please use the format specifier `%d`.

Comment: @Bohemian will you now let me post this comment as an answer please?

Comment: @WeatherVane You're awesome, thank you! I'm learning from two separate books and one uses `%i` while the other uses `%d`. I had no idea that there was a difference.

Comment: @WeatherVane go crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I amended your original program to deal with several issues. But the main one was to use the correct format specifier `%d` in `scanf()`. Using `%i` will interpret an input as `octal` if it has a leading `0` - very likely when typing a date, especially as you encourage that with the output format. Months `01` to `07` did not fail because the `octal` input works correctly - but `08` and `09` do not, as `8` and `9` do not exist in `octal` number representation.

I also checked the return value from `scanf()` to ensure the integer date fields were correctly entered. If you had done that, you would have seen there was something wrong there.

Other things I changed are:

Checked the date you entered to be valid to avoid the GIGO syndrome.

Avoided writing to the array of days per month as commented earlier.

Restricted the year to the Gregorian calendar, as some days were missing.

Separated `form` from `functionality`. For example, your `leapYear()` function checked for a leap year and also tested (inadequately) - and reported errors in the date entered.

Moved the global date variables to be local vars, which are passed as function arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct date {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

int daysPerMonth[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

int leapyear(int year) {
    return (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0));
    }

int validdate(struct date now) {
    int daysmon;
    if (now.year <= 1582)                   // pre-Gregorian
        return 0;
    if (now.month < 1 || now.month > 12)
        return 0;
    daysmon = daysPerMonth[now.month-1];
    if (leapyear(now.year) && now.month == 2)
        daysmon++;
    if (now.day < 1 || now.day > daysmon)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

struct date bumpdate(struct date now) {
    int daysmon = daysPerMonth[now.month-1];
    if (leapyear(now.year) && now.month == 2)
        daysmon++;
    if (++now.day > daysmon) {
        now.day = 1;
        if (++now.month > 12) {
            now.month = 1;
            now.year++;
        }
    }
    return now;
}

int main (void) {
    struct date today, tomorrow;
    printf("Enter today's date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
    if (3 != scanf("%d %*[/-] %d %*[/-] %d", &today.month, &today.day, &today.year)) {
        printf ("Need the proper date format\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (!validdate(today)) {
        printf ("Invalid date\n");
        return 1;
    }
    tomorrow = bumpdate(today);
    printf("Tomorrow's date is %02d/%02d/%04d", tomorrow.month, tomorrow.day, tomorrow.year);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks again! You more than solved my problem, you've shown me that I clearly need more practice with custom functions and structs. Very much appreciated.